# Scraping with PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, scrape

Here is a snippet of code I have so far

```
<?php 
include('include/simple_html_dom.php'); 

$url = 'http://www.nba.com/news/';
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('div[id=nbaNewsStories]') as $key)
{
    echo ($key->innertext) . "<br />";
}

?>
```

so far this display the links that I want from the section. My problem is that when you click on the articles that are pulled, links are relative and does not go to the webpage. I need to create an absolute url so when article title is clicked, it will go to `http://www.nba.com/news/title` of article

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $url = 'http://www.nba.com/news/'; 
$html = file_get_html($url);

Comment: foreach($html->find('div[id=nbaNewsStories]') as $key)
  {
   echo ($key->innertext) . "<br />";
  }

Comment: Look at PhpQuery, the most promising way to do it https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 0):

Include it before your foreach :

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $key)
{      
    $key->href = 'http://www.nba.com'.$key->href;    
}
```